# Displaying highest valued transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, inner-join, sql-limit

I want to write a query to display all information about the Customer who made the highest transaction. It is expected that the newly created amount due column be used to identify the highest transaction

[Top Table is my Customer table and the bottom table is the Transaction table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KivAn.png)

[image]

The highest transaction was made by Ken but I have to write a query that shows his entire row from the customer table and nothing else

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this will work for you :

```
select c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Addrass, c.PostCode, c.Email, c.DOB
from CustomerTable as c, TransactionTable as t
where c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
AND Amount_Due = (select Max(Amount_Due) from TransactionTable)
```

Comment: Got an error message:
"Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 149
Ambiguous column name 'CustomerID'."
And when I done Customer.CustomerID, it says "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 149
The multi-part identifier "Customer.CustomerID" could not be bound."

Comment: @HektikSwift seriously though, don't use that join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `order by` and `top`:

```
select c.*, t.*
from customer c
inner join (select top (1) with ties * from transaction t order by amount_due desc) t 
    on t.customerid = c.customerid
```

The subquery selects the transaction with the greatest `amount_due` (if there are ties, they are retained). We can then join this with the customer table.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 152
The multi-part identifier "Transaction.CustomerID" could not be bound.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 149
Ambiguous column name 'CustomerID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 149
Invalid column name 'Addrass'.

Comment: @HektikSwift: these column names come from the image that you have shown. If there are not your actual column names, then you would need to change them...

Comment: The image I have shown are screenshots from my actual tables so the columns names are as it appears on the images.